# Basic Django Query

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys, django-queryset

Simple scenario but can't figure out how to query for it:

We have a `Store` model and `Transaction` model. `Foreign Key` on `Transaction` model relating back to `Store`.

I want to query for a list of: *Only* stores that have done **at least one** transaction that day. All other stores should be excluded.

---

`Store.objects.filter(transaction__gt=0, transaction__date_created__gt='2016-06-01')`

When I tried the former query, I got a long list back:

```
[<Store: TrialStore>, <Store: TrialStore>, <Store: TrialStore>, ... ]
```

It's almost as if it's listing an instance of the store for each transaction. All I want back is a list of *each store* that has done at least one transaction for that day.

Right now, there's only one store in the database, so I should only be getting back one result.

**Edit**

`Store` Model:

```
class Store(models.Model):
  status = models.IntegerField(choices=status_choices, default=ACTIVE_STATUS)
  legal_name = models.TextField(verbose_name='Legal Name')
  mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
  email_address = models.EmailField(blank=True)
```

`Transaction` Model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
  store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created')
  status = models.IntegerField(choices=status_choices)
```

Comment: Can you show your models please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

```
Store.objects.filter(transaction__gt=0,
                     transaction__date_created__gt='2016-06-01').distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the datetime field as [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date) while querying:

```
Store.objects.filter(transaction__date_created__date=Date(2016, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
Store.objects.filter(
    transaction__gt=0, 
    transaction__date_created__year='2016', 
    transaction__date_created__month='06',
    transaction__date_created__day='01'
)
```

in your query, you are saying "give me all stores that have transactions since 2016.06.01". With my query, "give me all stores that have transactions from this day"

Comment: Even if I was actually querying for 'since 2016.06.01', shouldn't I still be getting only one result back? There's only one store that's been conducting transactions since then. Not three.